# Flexible vertical menu

Tags: html, css

I'm working on [this vertical menu](http://jsfiddle.net/DaXQP/). I need it to be flexible, so even longer text can be shown (as seen in the middle item). I want to keep the "padding" of the items, but I also want to increase the space between the lines for multi-line items (if I increase line-height, the distance from the edges gets bigger). How can I achieve that without increasing the "padding"? The images I use must have transparent background, so I can't use combination color-image (there is a gradient behind).

```
<div id="nav-list">
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><span class="button-middle">Button</span><span class="button-bottom"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span class="button-middle">Another button</span><span class="button-bottom"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span class="button-middle">The longest button in the world, even longer</span><span class="button-bottom"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span class="button-middle">Button</span><span class="button-bottom"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span class="button-middle">Btn</span><span class="button-bottom"></span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
border: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#nav-list {
width: 195px;
}

#nav-list ul {
list-style: none;
}

#nav-list ul li {
display: block;
margin: 5px 2px 0 5px;
font-size: 13px;
}

#nav-list ul li a {
display: block;
background: url('http://i41.tinypic.com/20h4hvp.png') top left no-repeat;
padding-top: 10px;
line-height: 10px;
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
}

#nav-list ul li a .button-middle {
width: 183px;
background: #b6b6b6;
padding-left: 5px;
display: block;
}

#nav-list ul li a .button-bottom {
width: 188px;
height: 10px;
background: url('http://i39.tinypic.com/2mrd343.png') top left no-repeat;
display: block;
}
```

Note: I can't use CSS3 because of its weak browser support.

Comment: Is this what you want to achieve? 
http://jsfiddle.net/DaXQP/2/

Comment: Which part of CSS3 are you thinking of NOT using because of 'weak browser supprt'?

Comment: @ajc No. I need the space between the top edge and the text and between the bottom edge and the text a bit smaller.

Comment: @Paulie_D There are still people using browsers like IE7, IE8 etc... And I thought of using round edges.

Comment: Yes...but what specific CSS3 option are you thinking of that might help but you choose not to use?

Comment: you might have to play around with .button-bottom s height and padding. 
http://jsfiddle.net/DaXQP/4/
Does this help?

Comment: @ajc It seems there is a bit of the bottom cut off. And there also seems to be 1px overlay of button-middle over the top picture.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is add something like:

```
span.button-middle {
    line-height: 1.2;
}
```

You could also decrease the line-height of the top and bottom of the button to compensate for the bigger middle section:

```
span.button-bottom {
    line-height: 0.8;
}
```

Comment: Changing line height for button-bottom has no effect. And setting line-height for button-middle has the same effect as setting it for the whole link.

Answer (score 0):

Well... after hours of struggle I managed to solve it. I had to use different images, add one more span and use some relative positioning.
http://jsfiddle.net/uNCsp/

```
<div id="nav-list">
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><span class="button-top"><span class="button-middle">Button</span></span><span class="button-bottom"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span class="button-top"><span class="button-middle">Another button</span></span><span class="button-bottom"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span class="button-top"><span class="button-middle">Even longer button button button button</span></span><span class="button-bottom"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span class="button-top"><span class="button-middle">Button</span></span><span class="button-bottom"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span class="button-top"><span class="button-middle">Button</span></span><span class="button-bottom"></span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav-list {
width: 195px;
}

#nav-list ul {
list-style: none;
}

#nav-list ul li {
display: block;
margin: 5px 2px 0 5px;
font-size: 13px;
}

#nav-list ul li a {
display: block;
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
}

#nav-list ul li a .button-top {
background: url('http://i43.tinypic.com/r0urzp.png') top left no-repeat;
display: block;
}

#nav-list ul li a .button-middle {
position: relative;
top: 6px;
background: transparent;
padding: 0 0 0 5px;
display: block; /* IE7 bug */
line-height: 16px;
padding-bottom: 3px;
}

#nav-list ul li a .button-bottom {
width: 188px;
height: 10px;
background: url('http://i44.tinypic.com/15fqbti.png') top left no-repeat;
display: block;
}

#nav-list ul li a:hover .button-top {
background: url('http://i39.tinypic.com/334qfsz.png') top left no-repeat;
}

#nav-list ul li a:hover .button-bottom {
background: url('http://i41.tinypic.com/2ewinti.png') top left no-repeat;
}
```

There is a problem in IE7 (marked in the code), but I believe I'll solve that quickly.